# IIS URL Rewrite rule - How can I remove some segments?

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have read the article [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) at iis.net and I would like to remove some segments from my urls.

for example, from:

```
/article/archive/2289/01/articleid/191/reftab/36/word1 word2 word3
```

to:

```
/article/articleid/191/word1-word2-word3
```

I have changed my web.config file with this but I don't be able to solve my issue:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove segments">
      <match url="^article/archive/2289/01/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article/articleid/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do it backwards.  The `<match>` element represents the friendly URL - the URL the user enters in the browser, the URL contained in a link, and the URL that IIS receives.

The `<action>` element represents the *unfriendly* URL - the ugly URL that you would have to use if you weren't using the rewrite module.

```xml
<match url="^article/articleid/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/article/archive/2289/01/articleid/{R:1}/reftab/36/{R:2}" />
```

The trouble here is that you probably don't want to hardcode `2289/01`, right?  You'll need to incorporate that into your friendly URL, or come up with some intermediary handler that can handle the request without those numbers.