# c# algorithm to check if a specific "word" exists in url

Tags: c#

I have an url:

`http://www.domain.com/path/path/path/path/file1.html`

And then another one:

`http://www.domain.com/path/path/external/path/path/file1.html`

Please notice `/external/` within the path.

Now the files "are the same" but they target different audience based on the `/external/`. If the path contains /external/ then it's for external use, otherwise is for internal use.

My question how do I relate these 2 files to each other? The '/external/' can be at any location within the path.

Each file might have max one external type or none at all.

Now to map the path to it's external type I am thinking to do like this:

For a specific file:

- targetPath = `http://www.domain.com/path/path/path/path/file1.html`
- get all file paths that contains `/external/` as a list

  - foreach path in list

    - remove `/external/`
    - if path == targetPath

      - external path for targetPath is path
    - break loop

Comment: So you have a solution, so what is your question exactly? Does your idea not work? What's not working in that case?

Comment: Why not simply replace `/external/` with `/` and see if the resulting path exists? And you ask for an algorithm, it seems you already have an algorithm, what is your question here?

Comment: I'm wondering if my algorithm will work for a dynamic path where /external/ can be located anywhere within the url. I am thinking it would work, just wanted to ask some opinions on the matter.

Comment: If you're in IIS, this sounds like a job for the [rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Comment: Some opinions about what; Whether it will work or not? Is it difficult to test if your solution would work, given that you have all the resource (that noone else has) for testing it?

Comment: How to pick out segments using rewrite : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268275/iis-url-rewrite-rule-how-can-i-remove-some-segments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually you don't have to add all the file paths which contain `/external/` into a list. You could simply use the `String.Replace` method.

```
string targetPath = "http://www.domain.com/path/path/external/path/path/file1.html";
targetPath = targetPath.Replace("/external/", "/");
```

This will replace all `/external/` parts in the string with a single `/`. And if the string doesn't contain any `/external/` string, it simply replaces nothing.